# How to check whether array includes certain value google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm using range.getValues() to load an array in Google Apps Script.
I want to loop through the array and do something if the array includes the value I'm looking for.

```
if (array.include("abc")){*doSomething*}
```

The problem is when I use this method, the array contain another arrays, so array.include() doesn't work.
I can use a workaround like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<=array.length; i++){ 
  if (array[i] == "abc"){*doSomething*}
```

I wonder are there a better way to do it?
I tried to use array.indexOf() but it returns -1 for 0th value, which is weird

Answer (score 1):

```
function find() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const haystack=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const needle="44";
  let found = false;
  haystack.forEach(r=>{
    r.forEach(c=>{
      if(c==needle) {
        found=true;
      }
    })
  });
  if(found) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Needle was found in haystack');
  }
}
```

or

```
function find() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const haystack=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const needle="44";
  let found = false;
  haystack.forEach(r=>{
    if(~r.indexOf(needle)) {
      found=true;
    }
  });
  if(found) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Needle was found in haystack');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendation**:

Alternatively, you can also try this way:

```
function arrayCheck(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var arr = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); //Get all values from sheet
  Logger.log(arr);
  arr.forEach(function(res) {
    if(res == 'abc'){
      Logger.log("Found a match");
      //do something
    }else{
      Logger.log(res+" does not match abc");
    }
  });
}
```

Here's a sample sheet where I've got all the array values from:

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]